# flex model: second row with width of element of first row

Tags: css, flexbox

I don't understand the flex model completly. In this example the elements of the first row (first and second) should be shown in a row: The first element 200px and the second one should have the rest space.

```css
 .wrapper {
   display: flex;
          width: 100%;
 }
 .first {
   width: 200px;
   background: red;
 }
 .second {
   flex: 1;
   background: blue;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first">first left</div>
  <div class="second">first right</div>
</div>
```

Now I want to add a third element, which should be placed right below the second one with the same width then the second element. So it shouldn't have 100% of the complete page, but only be shown below the second element.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first">first left</div>
    <div class="second">first right</div>
    <div class="third">second</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it this way, using the `calc` functionality.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.first {
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.second {
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  background: blue;
}

.third {
  background: yellow;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first">first left</div>
  <div class="second">first right</div>
  <div class="third">second right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't working correct, as the red and blue element aren't shown in one row (Safari) and what if I want to keep everything dynamic? red flex 1 and blue flex 3...

Comment: This is correct, just missing the `-webkit-` prefixes to work on some Safari versions.